# How to replace numbers with numbers stored in another file?

Tags: python

I have a Python function `evaluate_network` and following is its function call:

```
evaluate.evaluate_network(net, [1309,-2.553,1.44329], True, True)
```

Here, `[1309,-2.553,1.44329]` are inputs to this function. Each of these values are randomly generated and saved them in the following files: input1.txt, input2.txt, input3.txt.

```
input1.txt
1309
856
964
457
990

input2.txt
-2.553
1.284
1.795
0.426
-0.785

input3.txt
1.44329
0.84672
2.89524
1.4725
3.04526
```

need to replace each inputs from these files in each iteration as

```
evaluate.evaluate_network(net, [856,1.284,0.84672], True, True)
evaluate.evaluate_network(net, [964,1.795,2.89524], True, True)
evaluate.evaluate_network(net, [457,0.426,1.4725], True, True)
evaluate.evaluate_network(net, [990,-0.785,3.04526], True, True)
```

Actually, I need to generate more than 100 such random inputs and replace them in each run. How can we achieve this?

Comment: Are you looking for help with inputs or random number generation?

Comment: I need to take each inputs from these three files sequentially. My doubt is to how to do that using loop or so ??

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hardcode the numbers in the `evaluate_network` argument you can store them in variables.

You can then read the values from the text files line by line and update these variables in a loop.